# Vuetify: v-text-field does not look like the documentation

Tags: vue.js, npm, vuetify.js

I'm working with Vue using Vuetify, and I want to add a v-text-field task, but is not working like the documentation, https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/text-fields/#clearable. I'll leave some images below.

My input
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rVIkr.png)

the documentation input
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lRg7J.png)

**Code:**

**Home.vue**

```
<v-window-item :value="1">
          <v-row>
            <v-col cols="12" sm="6">
              <v-card-text class="mt-22">
                <h4 class="text-center">Login in to your Account</h4>
                <h6 class="text-center grey--text">
                  Login in to your account so you can continue building
                  <br />and editing your onboarding flows
                </h6>
                <v-row align="center" justify="center">
                  <v-col cols="12" sm="8">
                    <v-text-field
                      label="First Name"
                      outlined
                      dense
                      color="blue"
                      autocomplete="false"
                      class="mt-4"
                    />
                  </v-col>
                </v-row>
              </v-card-text>
            </v-col>
          </v-row>
        </v-window-item>
```

**App.vue**

```
  <template>
  <v-app>
    <v-main>
      <router-view />
    </v-main>
  </v-app>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  name: "App",

  components: {
   
  },

  data: () => ({
    //
  }),
};
```

**Package.json**

```
  {
  "name": "my-food-partner",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@tailwindcss/forms": "^0.3.4",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "vue": "^2.6.11",
    "vuetify": "^2.4.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.15.4",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/eslint-config-prettier": "^6.0.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^9.8.8",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "eslint": "^6.7.2",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.3.1",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^6.2.2",
    "material-design-icons-iconfont": "^6.1.1",
    "postcss": "^7.0.39",
    "prettier": "^2.2.1",
    "sass": "~1.32.0",
    "sass-loader": "^10.0.0",
    "tailwindcss": "npm:@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat@^2.2.17",
    "vue-cli-plugin-vuetify": "~2.4.3",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11",
    "vuetify-loader": "^1.7.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The two images look different because your code has the `dense` [prop](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-text-field/#props-dense) on `v-text-field` whereas the example doesn't. The inner blue rectangle is the "focus outline", you can override it using CSS but you shouldn't unless you have another style to separate the focused elements from the others (for [Accessibility concerns](https://www.a11yproject.com/posts/2013-01-25-never-remove-css-outlines/)).